# RestTemplate put with RequestParams

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have server side method

```
@PutMapping("/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies")
public ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch> updateNumberOfcopies(@RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId") long branchId) {
    bookCopiesRepository.updateNumberOfCopies(numberOfCopies, bookId, branchId);
    return new ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

i need to write a the method on client side, i tried this but is not working

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch> updateNumberOfcopies(@RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId") long branchId) {

    String url = "http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies";



    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
            // Add query parameter
            .queryParam("numberOfCopies", numberOfCopies).queryParam("bookId", bookId)
            .queryParam("branchId", branchId);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<LibraryBranch> entity = new HttpEntity<LibraryBranch>(headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(builder.toString(), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, LibraryBranch.class);
}
```

Comment: any error? and where this came from `lms/librarian/`?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute - i have this error

Comment: This `"http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies";` might be wrong try doing this in postman first or any web client

Comment: I do not know how to pass @RequestParam's to put method on server side

Comment: pass them as query param that should work

Comment: http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies - this is working . I already checked it

Comment: print the uri as `builder.toUriString()` and then check with that

Comment: @PutMapping("/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies") this is a working method on http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies

Comment: i need to get this method from http://localhost:8080/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies , for example

Comment: It's not clear for me, i will suggest to debug

Comment: All right! I have rest this resource on http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies  and method in the controller  is this: @PutMapping("/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies")
public ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch> updateNumberOfcopies(@RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId") long branchId) {
    bookCopiesRepository.updateNumberOfCopies(numberOfCopies, bookId, branchId);
    return new ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch>(HttpStatus.OK);
}